# Is there a better way of moving large data(~20 Million rows) from Hive database to Netezza database in R?

Tags: r, hive, odbc, netezza

I have a problem with transferring large volume of data(~20 Million rows , 20 columns) from Hive to Netezza.

Now, I am also looking for the best way or most efficient way to transfer data.

I have Hive and Netezza drivers successfully installed on my Windows 10 laptop with 16GB of memory.

I have noticed missing rows when I transfer large data from Hive to Netezza.I have previously successfully extracted small tables and written to Netezza 
 database using 'odbc' and 'DBI' packages in R. I also did transfer large volumes of data successfully using Alteryx but the license has expired and I would like to use R for the same task if possible.

```
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
# Creating Hadoop Hive connection using driver (HadoopHive)
con_hq <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "HadoopHive")
# Creating Netezza connection using re-configured driver(NZSQL)
con_nz <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "NZSQL") 
# Running the SQL query to get data from table1 from Hadoop database 
data <- dbGetQuery(con_hq, "select * from table1")
# writing the data frame 'data' into netezza database giving it a table 
#name 'nz_table1'
dbWriteTable( con_nz, "nz_table1", data)
```

It would be great if:

1. data can be moved in chunks or
2. move data from Hive to Netezza without having to transfer it to my computer in between or
3. Do the transfer without hogging my laptops' memory, so that I can use it for other tasks at the time of this transfer

Comment: Why are you doing it through your own pc? You could "simply" create an sqoop job in the hadoop cluster, it would take care of the parallelism itself after you define some parameters.

Comment: http://sqoop.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks, trying this using R or Python as they are tools I generally use for my analytic tasks, did not use sqoop before but surely will check it out now. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Personally I regard 20m rows going in or out of Netezza as ‘small’ or perhaps ‘medium’. Look at the ‘create external table’ syntax. That should do the trick in a performant way.